# Isotope masonry issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-isotope

This is driving me crazy!

My container div is `1170px` wide. I am trying to place 3 divs inside. One is `275px` wide, second is `580px` wide and 3rd `275px` wide. So in total - `1130px`.

And I can't fit the third one on the same line as the other two. It drops down no matter how wide I make the container div.

Please help, my brain is going to explode soon..

HTML:

```
   <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="grid">

                <div class="grid-item">
                    <img src="img/portfolio1.jpg" alt="">
                </div>

                <div class="grid-item width-double">
                    <img src="img/portfolio2.jpg" alt="">
                </div>

                <div class="grid-item">
                    <img src="img/portfolio3.jpg" alt="">
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.grid {

    .grid-item {
        padding: 0;

        width: 275px;
        height: 275px;
        float: left;

        &.width-double {
            width: 580px;
        }

        &.height-double {
            height: 580px;
        }
    }

}
```

JS:

```
$grid.isotope({
     itemSelector: '.grid-item',
     layoutMode: 'masonry'
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/meORoL

Comment: Could you create a similar [demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net). As CSS of Container and Row div is also needed to help you.

Comment: Yes, here it is: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/meORoL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZbBeEQ)

```
var $grid = $('.grid');
$grid.isotope(
{
      itemSelector: '.grid-item',
      masonry: 
      {
          columnWidth:1
      }
});
```

You have to set the Width of the column smthng like that

Answer (score 0):

Diptox's answer works, but I don't know if this is the best way to handle the situation.

Ideally you would set the columnWidth yourself, but when it is not set it is determined by the size of the first item in the grid. The reason your grid was breaking was because the larger item in the grid was not an even multiple of the first item. It had a width of 580px, whereas the columnWidth (determined by the first item in this case) had a with of 275px, so it did not "fit" into the 275px width array of columns set up by Masonry. Had it been set to an even multiple of 275px, such as 550px (275 * 2 = 550), it would have worked as expected.

I don't know whether there is anything to worry about with setting the columnWidth to 1, but I get the feeling that it is not ideal as it would be the default otherwise -- though it may be no problem at all.

Edit: Forgot to add code

CSS:

```
.grid-item.width-double {
  width: 550px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$grid.isotope({
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  masonry: {
        columnWidth: 275,
    }
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MabJdw